Hive ParseException-Unable to load Hive target table on Informatica PowerCenter
I am getting the following error when trying to load a Hive table using PowerCenter (ODBC connection):
: Rowdata: (Row Type=0(insert) Src Rowid=4 Targ Rowid=4
)
LIBRARY_NAME (LIBRARY_NAME:UniChar. 100:): "USECASE_COMMON"
TABLE_NAME (TABLE_NAME:UniChar. 100:): "CLIS_BUREAU_PLUS_INTERNAL_FINAL_FEATURES"
DISTINCT_COUNT (DISTINCT_COUNT:UniChar. 100:): "28391212"
STATUS (STATUS:UniChar. 100:): "TRUE"
YEAR (YEAR_UniChar. 100:): "2024"
MONTH (MONTH_UniChar. 100:): "6"
COUNT (COUNT_UniChar. 100:): "28391212"


FnName: Execute -- [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Function sequence error, SQLSTATE [S1010]
FnName: Execute -- [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:123 cannot recognize input near '?' ',' '?' in value row constructor, SQLSTATE [37000]

The target table on PowerCenter is configured as below. It takes the result of an query (which runs perfectly fine on Hue) and inserts the data



Column Name
Datatype




LIBRARY_NAME
varchar


TABLE_NAME
varchar


DISTINCT_COUNT
varchar


STATUS
varchar


YEAR_
varchar


MONTH_
varchar


COUNT_
varchar



Target table in Hive:



name
type




library_name
string


table_name
string


distinct_count
string


status
string


year_
string


month_
string


count_
string



I tried renaming the Count column to Count_ thinking it was some reserved keyword issue, but the problem still persists. The data types also look fine. I made a similar workflow that loads a CSV target and that works just fine.
I am at my wits end.
